# Sharepoint Library View - Role Based

Tags: roles

I have a library of reports. I also have Active Directory with users and groups. Groups are assigned access to the reports in the library. A group in this case is synonymous with a users role.

I would like to create a view on top of the library that displays a top layer of "folders" that are all of that users groups. Once the user clicks on one of his groups, the view will list all of the reports that the group has access to. A single report could show up multiple times for a single user, but under different groups.

Does Sharepoint support this type of view? I have attempted creating a custom view, but without success. I just want to ensure this is possible before I spend a bunch of time on it.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint will security trim the results for you. So in your case, if you have a library of folders with reports in them with custom permissions on each folder, then you'd get the results you are looking for.